# History API: Javascript Pushstate, get previous URL

Tags: url, history.js, html5-history

```
$(window).bind('statechange',function(){
     var State = History.getState(),
     url = State.url;
});
```

In the following function, url returns the *current* URL. What I'm looking for is, within that function, to get the previous URL, so for example, if I'm on `/cars/ferrari` and go to `/cars/ford`, `url` would return `cars/ford`, but I want to get `/cars/ferrari`.

How do I get the previous URL within a `statechange` event?

Comment: I would save the current url somewhere when you navigate via pushState.

Answer (score 11):

```
$(window).bind('statechange',function(){
    // Prepare Variables
    var State = History.getState(),
        url = State.url,
        states = History.savedStates,
        prevUrlIndex = states.length - 2,
        prevUrl = states[prevUrlIndex].hash;
});
```

That seems to do the trick! prevUrl gives me the desired URL.

Comment: This requires History.js, yes?

Comment: `$(window).bind('statechange')` doesn't seem to trigger anything for me

Answer (score 3):

All I would do is push the URL on to the state object so you can get it back again.

So this when you use pushState :

```
history.pushState(
  {'previous_url': document.location.href}, 
  document.title,
  "?some_query_string"
);
```

Then when you get the state it will have previous_url on it :)

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
alert(document.referrer);
```

Note:

> The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page
>   directly (not through a link, but, for example, via a bookmark). Since
>   this property returns only a string, it does not give you DOM access
>   to the referring page.

See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.referrer?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=document.referrer