# Find the last visited URL in javascript with history

Tags: javascript

I know about `document.referer` and this is not what I'm looking for.
It could probably be a solution but I want to retrieve it in local without using server.

### Steps :

- I'm pushing a new state in the current url of my page with `history.pushState('','','#test')`
- I'm going to the next page.
- And now I want to retrieve the URL but `history.previous` [has been erased since Gecko 26](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History#Properties).

Is there an other way of getting this value except from using cookies or sessionStorage?

Comment: My apologies. Answer in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298743/history-api-javascript-pushstate-get-previous-url) is using `history.js` library. You can use it as reference.

Comment: @Rajesh So I'm force to use (or read) an api just to use a function :/ Can't anybody unmark this post as duplicate ?

Comment: @Rajesh Just seen that, I didnt knew I could vote for reopen it. Thank you :)

Comment: reopened. Still sounds like a duplicate. You likely need to store the URL yourself regardless of framework

Comment: I personally think this is a duplicate... if you ignore the fact the linked question uses history.js, the answer is exactly what you want.

Comment: @mplungjan So I don't have other way than creating a cookie for exemple?

Comment: If you're pushing a new state using the history API (not history.js), just save the current URL. Why push a new state, and also redirect?

Comment: @evolutionxbox okay but the `var previousurl`will not be sent to the next page..? Unless I use session storage like cookies.

Comment: If you're using the history API the page won't refresh, so there's no need to use a cookie. Also, using cookies for this would be extremely difficult

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't think you understand my question. I want to retrieve the last url from the actual page. So i need the actual page to be load anyway. And using a cookie is not difficult but if I could avoid it it would be preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was that there is no option for that purpose in **local** without a server environment.

If you find this question it's that you're probably in the same problem as me so the only option I found was to use.

`sessionStorage.setItem('foo',val)` and retrieve it with `sessionStorage.getItem('foo')`.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to put the value in a parameter of the next page address, like so:

```
http://server.com/next-page-address/whatever.html?prevData=RequiredStateData
```

Note that using this approach, you might be exposed to users changing `RequiredStateData` in a malicious way. You can protect yourself using encryption or some checksum field.